# Pip не запускается после обновления

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

Пытаюсь настроить сервер на ubuntu.

Установил pip вот так:

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

Установилась древняя версия, обновил ее вот так:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

После этого pip3 не работает. Удалить и установить заново не помогает. В чем причина и что делать? Линукс знаю плохо, предвижу бессонные ночи.

Ошибка такая:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Comment: В том, что вы вмешались в системные пакеты, и не надо было обновлять pip в обход apt-get

Comment: А как надо было?

Comment: Например, никак? apt-get сам будет обновлять системные пакеты как ему надо

Comment: ну хоть pip на виртуальном оркужении python-то можно обновлять? А то пути линукса неисповедимы, я всего боюсь

Comment: Пакеты в виртуальном окружении не являются системными, так что почему бы и нет

Comment: Хорошо, переустановлю ОС от греха подальше и больше не буду так делать) Спасибо

Comment: А дефолтная версия python какая? Можно еще попробовать снести через purge, но нужно смотреть чтобы по зависимостям лишнего не потянуло Судя по всему обращение идет к pip, а не к pip3

Comment: А я уже переустановил ubuntu. Вроде все заработало.